# MySQL query optimization: how can I speed up this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

This is my table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `tab_adasf` (
  `adasf_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `adasf_shopId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `adasf_localId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `adasf_shopState` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adasf_shopCity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adasf_shopName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adasf_shopDoor` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adasf_computerName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adasf_channel` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `adasf_totalInside` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `adasf_totalOutside` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `adasf_createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adasf_id`),
  KEY `adasf_shopId` (`adasf_shopId`),
  KEY `adasf_localId` (`adasf_localId`),
  KEY `adasf_shopState` (`adasf_shopState`,`adasf_shopCity`,`adasf_shopName`,`adasf_shopDoor`),
  KEY `adasf_computerName` (`adasf_computerName`,`adasf_channel`,`adasf_createdAt`),
  CONSTRAINT `tab_adasf_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`adasf_shopId`) REFERENCES `tab_shop` (`shop_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1453500 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As AUTO_INCREMENT's value says: it has 1453500 rows.

In order to generate a XML file, I need the resultset as follows:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(adasf_shopState) AS adasf_shopState,
    UPPER(adasf_shopCity) AS adasf_shopCity,
    UPPER(adasf_shopName) AS adasf_shopName,
    UPPER(adasf_shopDoor) AS adasf_shopDoor,
    adasf_computerName,
    adasf_channel,
    SUM(adasf_totalInside) AS adasf_totalInside,
    SUM(adasf_totalOutside) AS adasf_totalOutside,
    YEAR(adasf_createdAt) AS year,
    MONTH(adasf_createdAt) AS month,
    DAY(adasf_createdAt) AS day,
    HOUR(adasf_createdAt) AS hour
    FROM tab_adasf 
WHERE 1=1 AND adasf_shopId = '1' AND HOUR(adasf_createdAt) BETWEEN '10:00' AND '21:00' 
GROUP BY
    UPPER(adasf_shopState),
    UPPER(adasf_shopCity),
    UPPER(adasf_shopName),
    UPPER(adasf_shopDoor),
    adasf_computerName,
    adasf_channel,
    YEAR(adasf_createdAt),
    MONTH(adasf_createdAt),
    DAY(adasf_createdAt),
    HOUR(adasf_createdAt)
ORDER BY
    UPPER(adasf_shopState),
    UPPER(adasf_shopCity),
    UPPER(adasf_shopName),
    UPPER(adasf_shopDoor),
    UPPER(adasf_computerName),
    adasf_channel,
    adasf_createdAt
```

It takes 3 minutes to run and fetch.

My question is: what am I doing wrong? How can I speed up this query or table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what's the difference between ORDER BY UPPER(x) and ORDER BY x ? Same with GROUP BY... and shop_id is also an integer - all these tiny things make tiny differences - but the key really is indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, a query like this that reports on the whole table is inherently time-consuming. That being said, here's a suggestion or two.

First, eliminate the `UPPER()` function calls in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL's collations are case-insensitive anyhow.

Second, instead of `GROUP BY`  year, month, day, hour, try using this expression in the GROUP BY.

```
 DATE_FORMAT(adasf_createdAt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

This will basically round off your `createdAt` value to the immediately preceding hour.

Third, let's refactor the `WHERE` item that reads

```
 HOUR(adasf_createdAt) BETWEEN '10:00' AND '21:00'
```

It should say

```
 HOUR(adasf_createdAt) BETWEEN 10 AND 21
```

And if you remove that from your main query it will speed up. You can then wrap your query in another query like so:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( /*your whole query without the WHERE HOUR() BETWEEN clause */
       ) AS q
  WHERE q.hour BETWEEN 10 AND 21
```

Finally, try creating a compound covering index on

```
 adasf_shopId, adasf_shopState, adasf_shopCity, adasf_shopName, adasf_shopDoor,
 adasf_computerName, adasf_channel,  adasf_CreatedAt, 
 adasf_totalInside, adasf_totalOutside
```

This index has all the information required to satisfy your query arranged in sequential order. It's possible this will speed up your query.

So, your ultimate query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
SELECT
       UPPER(adasf_shopState) AS adasf_shopState,
       UPPER(adasf_shopCity) AS adasf_shopCity,
       UPPER(adasf_shopName) AS adasf_shopName,
       UPPER(adasf_shopDoor) AS adasf_shopDoor,
       adasf_computerName,
       adasf_channel,
       SUM(adasf_totalInside) AS adasf_totalInside,
       SUM(adasf_totalOutside) AS adasf_totalOutside,
       YEAR(adasf_createdAt) AS year,
       MONTH(adasf_createdAt) AS month,
       DAY(adasf_createdAt) AS day,
       HOUR(adasf_createdAt) AS hour
 FROM tab_adasf 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND adasf_shopId = '1'  
GROUP BY
      adasf_shopState,
      adasf_shopCity,
      adasf_shopName,
      adasf_shopDoor,
      adasf_computerName,
      adasf_channel, 
      DATE_FORMAT(adasf_createdAt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
ORDER BY
      adasf_shopState,
      adasf_shopCity,
      adasf_shopName,
      adasf_shopDoor,
      adasf_computerName,
      adasf_channel, 
      DATE_FORMAT(adasf_createdAt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
     ) AS q
  WHERE q.hour BETWEEN 10 AND 21
```

It's possible this simplification of your query, combined with the covering index, will make the query faster.

Please note that I haven't debugged this query and don't have the test data to do so.

Comment: Yes, the default collation for `utf8` is `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Thank you @Ollie Jones, the query is now 33% fast. But unfortunately I can't create such index: The DB returns: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Comment: You have a lot of `varchar(255)` columns in your table. Each of those needs 765 bytes (3x255) in the index because of Unicode. It might be possible to shorten those columns. If so, maybe you can get the index to fit in 3072 bytes.

Comment: I made a mistake in my list of columns for the big index, and just corrected it. Sorry about that

Comment: If I may ask, what did you actually do and how much performance increase did you get?

Answer (score 2):

To speed up the query, you can create an index on `tab_adasf(adasf_shopId)`.  This should help performance a lot if you have many shops.

If you need to do a lot of queries of this type, then consider splitting the `adasf_createdAt` column into a date component and a time component.  Then you can create an index on `tab_adasf(adasf_shopId, adasf_createdAt_time)`, further helping the query.

In general splitting the time from the datetime is not recommended unless you have a good reason.  Increasing performance of this type of query constitutes a "good reason".

Comment: Yes, the goal in separating the time out into a separate column is to get rid of the `HOUR()` function in the `WHERE` clause so you can actually utilize an index on the hour. I.e. Instead of `HOUR(adasf_createdAt) BETWEEN '10:00' AND '21:00'`, you would write `adasf_createdAt_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '21:00'`. Using a function against a column prevents MySQL from using any index on that column for searches.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: This answer will not work in MySQL.**

You're having to use a full table scan to check every row to see if it matches `HOUR(adasf_createdAt) BETWEEN '10:00' AND '21:00'`.

Create a functional index on `HOUR(adasf_createdAt)`.

Also, see http://use-the-index-luke.com for an excellent tutorial on how to use indexes effectively.

Comment: It's a MySQL RDMS. Unless the OQ is using MariaDB 10+, no functional index capability is available.

Comment: Argh, thanks.  Yet another MySQL shortcoming I was not aware of.

Comment: I thnk I should try NoSQL with MongoDB. What do you think about it?

Comment: The question of switching to NoSQL is an entirely different question. Please ask it separately.